# Mongodb find() using Node not returning all documents (strange behavior)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor with Node to retrieve a list of vehicles from a MongoDB collection, hosted on mLab. I recently noticed that `find()` in my js app was not returning all the matching documents in the collection. Using Mongo shell and the search on mLab both return the correct number of results.

Here's a sample document from the collection that isn't returned when it 
 should be:

```
{
    "_id": "VIN",
    "updatedOn": "Fri Aug 11 2017 11:27:40 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "clientId": "1001",
    "crushVersion": "v.3.42",
    "yardName": "YARD NAME",
    "yardCity": "CITY",
    "yardState": "STATE",
    "stockNumber": "STK123447",
    "iStatus": "0",
    "location": "YARD",
    "year": "2003",
    "make": "AUDI",
    "model": "A6",
    "vehicleRow": "32",
    "yardDate": "2017-08-10T18:09:38.363",
    "batchNumber": "STK123447",
    "lastUpdate": "08/11/2017 01:31:31 AM",
    "color": "SILVER",
    "vin": "VIN",
    "reference": "",
    "milage": "24"
}
```

...and one that's returned as expected:

```
{
    "_id": "VIN",
    "updatedOn": "Fri Aug 11 2017 11:27:40 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "clientId": "1112",
    "crushVersion": "v.3.42",
    "yardName": "YARD NAME",
    "yardCity": "CITY",
    "yardState": "STATE",
    "stockNumber": "STK02752",
    "iStatus": "0",
    "location": "YARD",
    "year": "2003",
    "make": "AUDI",
    "model": "A6",
    "vehicleRow": "600",
    "yardDate": "2017-07-20T10:28:54.407",
    "batchNumber": "STK02752",
    "lastUpdate": "08/11/2017 08:30:30 AM",
    "color": "GRAY",
    "vin": "VIN",
    "reference": "",
    "milage": "1"
}
```

...and the js code for 'find';

```
MongoClient.connect(
    url,
    Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, db) => {
        if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err)
        const inv = db.collection('inventory'),
            userId = user._id,
            picks = _picks, 
            /* _picks comes from a user-populated form as an array of objects. */
            makes = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.make.toUpperCase()
            }),
            models = picks.map(pick => {
                return pick.model.toUpperCase()
            }),
            yards = user.profile.yards.map(yard => {
                return yard.yard
            })
        if (picks.length > 0) {
            inv
                .find({
                    $or: user.profile.picks.map(p => ({
                        year: { $gte: p.minYear, $lte: p.maxYear }
                    })),
                    make: { $in: makes },
                    model: { $in: models },
                    yardName: { $in: yards }
                })
                .toArray(
                    Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, docs) => {
                        if (err) throw new Meteor.Error(err)

                        console.log(docs)
                    })
                )
        }
    })
)
```

Now here's the weird part. All the documents returned have a `yardDate` of `2017-7-31` or older. This may be a coincidence, but I don't think so. My collection has around 21000 documents and all queries exhibit the same behavior.

I looked at this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655828/mongodb-find-query-not-returning-all-values%20Link), but some of my queries only have one or two results, so I don't think it's a buffer overflow issue.

Thanks for any help you can give!

**Update:**
I made a little test file to see if there's something up the chain from my `find()` that may be messing with the query. Here's the code for that:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    url = 'mongodb://user:password@ipaddress/dbname'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    const inv = db.collection('inventory')

    inv.find({ year: '2003', model: 'A6' }).toArray((err, docs) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err)
        console.log(docs)
        db.close()
    })
})
```

This should return five documents, but only returns two... all with a `yardDate` older than `2017-07-31`.

**Update:**

I added a 'missing' result and a 'found' result.

Comment: It sounds like there is some kind of data problem. Have you tried exporting the data and reimporting it to a new database? Maybe the indexes are corrupted somehow. 

OR...

Your example shows the year is a string, do the missing records have numbers in the year field?

Comment: I like both ideas, but nope. I dropped the collection and created it again with the same result. In each document, the properties are all strings, whether they contain numbers or not. Thanks, though!

Comment: I just added examples of two documents, one that isn't returned and one that is.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out... when I moved my database to mLab, I didn't find all the urls in the app and change them. The original database was still talking, so I was getting the 'old' results.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :) At least you had enough guts to own up to the mistake. Put it down to experience - that one won't happen to you again, will it?