# Javascript: Write and complete an existing file

Tags: node.js

I try to write some nodejs code that completes an existing file. But each time I start the script, it over writes the content of my test file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var writer = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt', {flags: 'w'});
writer.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('data has been saved successfully');
});

function writeInList(id) {
  console.log(id); 
  writer.write(id+' \n');
}

for (var id = 0; id<10; id++){
  writeInList(id);
}

writer.end();
```

Of course I have searched for a solution:

[Writing large files with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486683/writing-large-files-with-node-js)

But I'm not able to make it run. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: set your stream option flags to 'a' (append)

Comment: thanks. Where can I find an overview about all options. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options is not helpful for me.

Comment: Only reason I know is that I had the exact same issue yesterday. I've yet to find a list of possible flags values for stream options... have been unable to locate that info in the NodeJS docs.